# Error getting access token from GoogleCredential

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, access-token, credentials, google-oauth-java-client

I am trying to get an access token to use the Cloud SQL Admin API to export a table as CSV to google cloud storage. I keep getting this error: `Scopes not configured for service account. Scoped should be specified by calling createScoped or passing scopes to constructor.` everytime I call  `credentials.refreshAccessToken();`In the code below.
Could someone guide me as to what I'm doing wrong here

```
       Set<String> oAuthScopes = new HashSet<String>();
       oAuthScopes.add(SQLAdminScopes.CLOUD_PLATFORM);
       oAuthScopes.add(SQLAdminScopes.SQLSERVICE_ADMIN);

       GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
       credentials.createScoped(oAuthScopes);
       AccessToken access_token = credentials.refreshAccessToken();

        try {

            httppost.addRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httppost.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token.getTokenValue());

            httppost.setRequestEntity(
                    new StringRequestEntity(
                            "{\"exportContext\":" +
                                    "\"fileType\": \"CSV\"," +
                                    "\"uri\":" + EXPORT_BUCKET +
                                    "\"databases\": [\"" + DATABASE_NAME + "\"]," +
                                    "\"csvExportOptions\": " +
                                    "{" +
                                    "\"selectQuery\":\"" + SQL_QUERY + "\" " +
                                    "} " +
                                    "} " +
                                    "}",
                            "application/json",
                            "UTF-8"));

            httpclient.executeMethod(httppost);
            String response = new String(httppost.getResponseBody());
            httppost.releaseConnection();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException unsupportedEncodingException) {
            unsupportedEncodingException.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This exception seems to come from the fact that the Application Default Credentials authorization strategy for client [libraries](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application) will kick in once you set 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'

Also, you can create a scoped credential like this:

```
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault().createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
```